# My CAPTCHA doesn't work. Warning: imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in W:\domains\shop\reg\reg_captcha.php on line 35

Tags: php, warnings, captcha, imagettftext

I am developing a site on a localhost and reached the moment of creating the registration form and decided to create my own captcha. But I got such errors:
 
**Warning: imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in W:\domains\shop\reg\reg_captcha.php on line 35**
**Warning: imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in W:\domains\shop\reg\reg_captcha.php on line 47**
[https://i.imgur.com/HL5SO8z.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHImn.png)
This is how I access the captcha in register.php:

```
 <div id="captcha">
    <img src="/reg/reg_captcha.php" />
    <input type="text" name="reg_captcha" id="reg_captcha" />
     <p id="reload_captcha">Update code</p>
 </div>
```

Here is the CAPTCHA code:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $width = 100;                 
 $height = 50;
 $font_size = 17.5;     
 $let_amount = 4;    
 $fon_let_amount = 30; 
 $path_fonts = 'fonts/';


 $letters = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','2','3','4','5','6','7','9');
 $colors = array('10','30','50','70','90','110','130','150','170','190','210');

 $src = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
 $fon = imagecolorallocate($src,255,255,255);
 imagefill($src,0,0,$fon);

 $fonts = array();
 $dir=opendir($path_fonts);
 while($fontName = readdir($dir))
 {
   if($fontName != "." && $fontName != "..")
   {
     $fonts[] = $fontName;
   }
 }
 closedir($dir);

 for($i=0;$i<$fon_let_amount;$i++)
 {
   $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($src,rand(0,255),rand(0,255),rand(0,255),100); 
   $font = $path_fonts.$fonts[rand(0,sizeof($fonts)-1)];
   $letter = $letters[rand(0,sizeof($letters)-1)];
   $size = rand($font_size-2,$font_size+2);
   imagettftext($src,$size,rand(0,45),rand($width*0.1,$width-$width*0.1),rand($height*0.2,$height),$color,$font,$letter);
 }

 for($i=0;$i<$let_amount;$i++)
 {
   $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($src,$colors[rand(0,sizeof($colors)-1)],$colors[rand(0,sizeof($colors)-1)],$colors[rand(0,sizeof($colors)-1)],rand(20,40)); 
   $font = $path_fonts.$fonts[rand(0,sizeof($fonts)-1)];
   $letter = $letters[rand(0,sizeof($letters)-1)];
   $size = rand($font_size*2.1-2,$font_size*2.1+2);
   $x = ($i+1)*$font_size + rand(4,7);
   $y = (($height*2)/3) + rand(0,5);
   $cod[] = $letter;   
   imagettftext($src,$size,rand(0,15),$x,$y,$color,$font,$letter);
 }

 $_SESSION['img_captcha'] = implode('',$cod);

 header ("Content-type: image/gif"); 
 imagegif($src);

?>
```

Comment: I am suposing you are trying a captch of 4 letters. Why do you need this loop ? for($i=0;$i<$fon_let_amount;$i++)

Comment: are you sure that fonts are saved at reg/fonts ?